# Using object key as the include file in twig template

Tags: php, twig

Good morning,

Im trying to build a component where the data arrives in json form from a cms. I need to be able to use an object from the array as the file to include in the twig template. Something like this..

```
{%cards [{component: '@-card', cardOptions: {''}}, {component: '@-card_small', cardOptions: {''}}] %}

{% for card in cards %} {% include card.component with card.cardOptions only %} {% endfor %}
```

The problem I have it doesn't seem to parse the '@' from the json and I get the error "file.indexOf is not a function". The project is set up to use '@' as the prefix so I have no way to change that. Iv tried to concatenate in various ways but nothing works. Without the '@' symbol it parses as I expected.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, or what isn't working

Comment: So I want to include the file {% include '@-card' with {} only %} but by including it from the json so it would be {% include card.component with {} only %}. It doesn't allow me to include @-card by referencing it with card.component

Comment: Twig is expecting a namespace when using `@`, can't you just replace the `@` in template names after fetching the `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your replace suggestion DarkBee, I fixed it by using

```
{% for card in cards %}
  {% set card = '@' ~ card.component %}
  {% include card with {card.cardOptions, card:card} only %}
{% endfor %}
```